# How to schedule cron jobs in linux?

Tags: linux, cron, date

I have script files.
.file I need to run only on the first day of the every month.

How can I do this with my cron job?

```
52 07 * * * bash '/home/linux/tanu/cat.sh'
```

Comment: You've changed the question so that it no longer makes sense. I rolled back the question to the previous revision that was active when you accepted the given answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
# * * * * *
# | | | | |
# | | | | day of week 0-7 (0 or 7 is Sun, or use names)
# | | | month 1-12 (or names)
# | | day of month 1-31
# | hour 0-23
# minute 0-59 

# runs on every 1st of month at 7:52am
52 7 1 * * bash '/home/linux/tanu/cat.sh'    

# runs on all other days at 7:52am
52 7 2-31 * * bash '/home/linux/tanu/cat.sh'
```

I hope that's correct.

Comment: Related: [Crontab Guru link](https://crontab.guru/#52_7_1_*_*)

Comment: @Kusalananda Added to bookmarks :)